# Android data partition size

Tags: android

I'm building Android from source code, and install it on a custom device, where eMMC userdata partition may be one of a few different sizes.
How can I build userdata.img only once, so that it fits all the devices ?
What are the required settings in fstab.whatever and BoardConfig.mk:BOARD_USERDATAIMAGE_PARTITION_SIZE ?

Motivation, why I think this is possible at all:
Nexus 4 device arrives in two versions: with 8GB or 16GB storage.
However, factory images for Nexus devices (https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) do not take it into account - there is a single Android image. Which makes me believe, the data partition is automatically expanded till the end of the storage device.

Can anyone spill some light on how is this achievable ?
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this works as follows:
Userdata.img partition image size fits the minimal physical partition size there might be (~6 GB on Nexus 4, ~12 GB on Nexus 5). So after flashing userdata.img, to 16 GB-Nexus 4 device, we find storage capacity has decreased.
To span (ext-4) file system on all the userdata partition, "factory reset" should be performed.
This works because factory reset is equivalent to re-formatting the userdata partition. Pay attention, re-formatting rather than deleting full contents. Creating (ext-4) file system from scratch will span all the physically available volume capacity.
To conclude, there is apparently no magic per se.

Reference:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/32-gb-nexus-5-12-55-gb-storage-space-t2938406